# Accessing nested elements with multiple classes with querySelector

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using pure JS

I've got a grid of 6 big squares and each big square contains 9 smaller squares. HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row r1" style="background: red">
    <div class="square o1">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square o2">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square o3">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then i'm running a JS code that rolls dices and depending on the diceroll certain numbers of inner squares will be filled with text and those squares will be chosen at random.
Code should run like this:
Go to first big square (i=1) -> roll the "dice" -> for every numOfTerrain chose smaller square being inside of ".square o+i" at random and fill it with text.

Here is my current code, which fails at the final loop with "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null"

```
var dice1, dice2;
for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
  dice1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  dice2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  var diceroll = dice1 + dice2;

  //checking number of terrains for each main square
  var numOfTerrain;
  switch (diceroll) {
    case 2:
    case 3:
      numOfTerrain = 0;
      break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 9:
    case 10:
      numOfTerrain = 2;
      break;
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
      numOfTerrain = 1;
      break;
    case 11:
    case 12:
      numOfTerrain = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4));
  }

  //Randomizing the placement of terrains in squares
  var rolls = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < numOfTerrain; j++) {
    rolls[j] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
    while (rolls[j] == rolls[j - 1]) {
      rolls[j] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
    }
    document.querySelector('.o' + (i + 1) + ' ' + '.i' + (rolls)).textContent = "text";
  }
}
```

Perhaps I am trying to access the children of `.square oNUMBER` in a wrong way?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: Good idea actually, but will do it tomorrow, i'm gonna lose my internet connection in 5 minutes due to "scheduled maintance".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a brief look at the code, I think there were a couple of bugs:

1. Main loop caused `i` to be set to `7` on the last run through, causing issues trying to select a missing `.o7` class
2. `document.querySelector()` call was also referencing `rolls` as an array, rather than the current index (updated to `rolls[j]`)

See below for a demo. Bit meaningless without the accompanying CSS, but should hopefully be enough to get you back on track ;)

```js
var dice1, dice2;
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  dice1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  dice2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  var diceroll = dice1 + dice2;

  //checking number of terrains for each main square
  var numOfTerrain;
  switch (diceroll) {
    case 2:
    case 3:
      numOfTerrain = 0;
      break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 9:
    case 10:
      numOfTerrain = 2;
      break;
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
      numOfTerrain = 1;
      break;
    case 11:
    case 12:
      numOfTerrain = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4));
  }

  //Randomizing the placement of terrains in squares
  var rolls = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < numOfTerrain; j++) {
    rolls[j] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
    while (rolls[j] == rolls[j - 1]) {
      rolls[j] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
    }
    document.querySelector('.o' + (i + 1) + ' ' + '.i' + rolls[j]).textContent = "text";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row r1" style="background: red">
    <div class="square o1">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square o2">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square o3">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square o4">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square o5">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square o6">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, the main problem was indeed using "rolls" instead of "rolls[j]". Wont ever code again when im sleepy... Thank you so much!